# How can I only compile and show a part of an document in TeXStudio

Tags: texstudio

In my special case I want to place a text in a graphic via overpic. It always takes quite long to compile and show the whole document or also even the whole chapter (I think because there are some graphics in it). Is there a possibility that only that one graphic with the text (it's all in an figure section) gets compiled and is shown?

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, twoside]{scrreprt} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}      
\usepackage{pgfplots}  
\usepackage{overpic}   
\usepackage{amssymb}    
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!h]
    \centering
    \begin{overpic}
        [width=0.3\textwidth]{sample_layout}
        \put(40,60){pin1}
    \end{overpic}
    \caption{scheme}
    \label{fig:sample_layout} 
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you please explain better? I have understood very little. What would you like to do? Is there an image you could insert, or, even better, a small LaTeX code?

Comment: Why you don't split your code up?

Comment: Play with your graphic in its own file and when you're done copy the thing back into your document.

Comment: Presumably you have an `\begin{overpic}...\end{overpic}` environment? You can try the inline preview (highlight the entire environment, right click and select `Preview selection/parenthesis`).

Comment: I've already tried that but where can I find the preview then?

Comment: @vogs It should appear inline (right below your code in the editor view).

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use inline preview: 
Highlight the relevant section that you want to compile (here, the `overpic` environment), right click and select `Preview selection`. 
The preview will appear below your code (by default), and updates automatically when you change anything within the preview selection block.

GIF:

(I'm not clicking 'compile' or any other buttons in between the changes you see below in the gif.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{overpic, color}

\begin{document}
    \begin{overpic}[abs,unit=1mm,scale=.25,grid]{example-image}
        \put(3,15){\color{blue}\huge\LaTeX}
    \end{overpic}
\end{document}
```

Note that this functionality extends to environments like equations, inline math, tables (tabular) etc. as well.

The relevant settings for this can be found in `Options -> Configure TeXstudio -> Preview`.

---

### Addendum

As of TXS 2.12.10, TeXstudio uses the [`preview`](https://ctan.org/pkg/varwidth) + [`varwidth`](https://ctan.org/pkg/varwidth) packages for the inline preview functionality mentioned above.
`preview` doesn't play well with floating environments (like `figure`), so it's best to just stick to previewing non-floating stuff.

The 'error' that you receive when you try to inline preview a floating environment is the well-known "not in outer par mode" error.

For your specific case, it works if you just preview the `overpic` environment by itself (proof):

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Tried that but I always get the following error:Process started: pdflatex.exe -interaction=nonstopmode -ini "&pdflatex hB13868 \dump"

Process started: pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "F13868".tex

Process exited with error(s)

Comment: @vogs Please provide the non-working example. If I can't reproduce it, I can't help.

Comment: Code sample added

Comment: @vogs see updated answer. don't preview the figure environment, just the overpic environment. it should work.

Comment: How did you create the animation?